# How to create featured article listing with an featured image in joomla?

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

I am pretty new to joomla. The effect I am trying to achieve is http://www.greenjourneys.nl/individuele-reizen.html this.  Notice, there is an featured image for each articles.

Can you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just include the image before the page break.
There are a number of components that will allow you to resize the photo easily (or create tumbnails 'on the fly') which would work great for something like that.

However if you just have small images you want to use - simply include the image into the article before the pagebreak and use CSS to control how it lays out on the front page.

You can decide if you want the intro text to show in the main article or not, if you do - then you won't have to include the image again (it will show by default) but if you do not want the intro text to show, just be aware that the image you choose for the front page won't display in the article when clicked on.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Boring?  Really?  This is the way it's properly done in Joomla! - don't ask for help and the criticize when it's given.  You could also use something like SOBI2 - but again, with the extremely limited information you've given (no component ideas, no version of Joomla, etc etc) the proper way to do it is just as I described.  You probably should have included "I want something exciting" into your post if that is what you wanted; as opposed to the minimal effort you actually put into it.